# Error CS0426 The type name 'HorizontalToggleSwitch' does not exist in the type 'ToggleSwitch'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, typeerror, visual-studio-2019

- Installed a nuget package ToggleSwitch
- Trying to use it in one wpf window

```
<Window x:Class="TeamsWizard.Forms.TeamsInputWizard"            
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:vsshell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TeamsWizard.Forms"
            xmlns:ctr="clr-namespace:TeamsWizard"
            xmlns:Borders="clr-namespace:ToggleSwitch.Borders;assembly=ToggleSwitch"
            xmlns:Utils="clr-namespace:ToggleSwitch.Utils;assembly=ToggleSwitch"
            xmlns:ToggleSwitch="clr-namespace:ToggleSwitch;assembly=ToggleSwitch"                     
            >
```

```
<ToggleSwitch:HorizontalToggleSwitch x:Name="chkTab"                                                       IsChecked="False"                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
Width="60" />
```

When I press F12 on above line, It shows the metadata.That means HorizontalToggleSwitch is a type under ToggleSwitch. I am not sure how to make build successful?

Note : When I remove "x:Name=chkTab" build is successful.

Comment: I ran the code you provided and did not reproduce the error.Is there any other code not provided for the error? By the way, my project target Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: Did you use this attribute "x:Name="chkTab" ?

Comment: Yes, I used x:Name attribute

Comment: Even I use the same target framework 4.7.2. Can you share your code link, so that i can download.?

Comment: My code is exactly the same as yours.Can you create a new test project that only tests this functionality?